# I followed all instruction below to install bootstrap. The screen is show below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYnmW.png)[homeScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcFDJ.png)

I want to use nav bar in my homescreen. 
I already followed all instruction. Can anyone know the problem of this one?

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have no css at all.. Did you included it in your layout?

Could you please add some code ? Your layout ? Screenshot of your assets?

Comment: in assert style sheet